# How to run JS in VS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to run JS in VS code everything run well but. Methods like confirm or prompt. Is does not work.

error:

*prompt("hello")
^
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined*

Comment: `prompt`, `confirm`, `alert` are not part of JavaScript. These kinds of methods are provided by the browser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. installing Node Js and
2. Add [Code Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

Comment: `prompt`, `confirm` and `alert` are not defined in Node.js.